# what is a typical channel : amqrmppa ratio?

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

We are seeing that for about 175 channels that are open to queue manager there are about 450 amqrmppa processes running, I'm not sure that is how the ratio should be? If this is too high what's the best way to troubleshoot this and be able to pin point which IP has opened how many amqrmppa processes?

We are using MQ v9.1.0.6 on rhel7 machine.

Answer (score 1):

To understand which channels are running inside which `amqrmppa` processes, use the following command:-

```
DISPLAY CHSTATUS(*) JOBNAME
```

which will give you output like:-

```
AMQ8417I: Display Channel Status details.                                                                                  
   CHANNEL(MQG1.TO.MQG2)                   CHLTYPE(SDR)                                                                    
   CONNAME(127.0.0.1(1702))                CURRENT                                                                         
   JOBNAME(00007DFC00000001)               RQMNAME(MQG2)                                                                   
   STATUS(RUNNING)                         SUBSTATE(MQGET)                                                                 
   XMITQ(MQG2)
```

Looking at the `JOBNAME` field, it is two hex values (on Windows and Unix anyway) containing the process ID of the `amqrmppa` process, in my example `0x00007DFC` and then the thread ID within that process.

If you view all your channel status records in a tool that allows you to sort the output by any field, then do so, and sort by Job Name to see all the channels grouped by the process ID they are running inside.

It is rather surprising that you have more `amqrmppa` processes running that you have active channels. Usually there would be less `amqrmppa` processes than channels because several channels will run inside one `amqrmppa` (ReMote Pool Process). This suggests that perhaps you have earlier had many more channels and thus needed many more `amqrmppa` processes, but now most of those channels have ended. I would have expected an "empty" `amqrmppa` process to end when it no longer had anything to do, a small number will stay around for new channels that start later, but not 200 of them.

Comment: @Morgan Hughson, Thanks a lot for this information. I do see there are multiple channel threads ids for each amqmppra processes in my system.
we have 150 channels currently running and looking at the number of threads for each process there should be only 20 - 30 amqmppra processes running on the system, but I'm listing 529 of them now! So too many zombie processes.
How can I control them? any timeout that I can configure to terminate idle processes?

Comment: @SKMo there is no timeout as they are supposed to automatically end when they have no more threads. I suppose it is possible that there is some thread running in them that isn't associated with a channel and so doesn't show up on the command I gave you, but I don't know what that would be. You should probably raise a case with IBM since the behavior you describe is not at all expected and I would say is defective. It is possible there is an APAR for this already but it certainly should be looked into if there isn't.

Comment: will open a case, thank you and appreciate the support.